# Convert {String} to 'String' in Saelsforce LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

I want to pass the test case assertEquals with String 'success'. But the value getting from the query like {success}. How do I convert 'success' to {success}

```
System.assertEquals('success'', myMap.keySet());
```

in myMap, the key is 'success' But when I use it to myMap.KeySet(), it is returning {success}.

Answer (score 2):

`keySet()` returns the [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) which is represented by `{...}` in debug (same with list also). You should rather check if `success` exists in set:

```
System.assert(myMap.keySet().contains('success'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want to compare the set to another set:

```
System.assertEquals(
  new Set<String>{'success'}, 
  myMap.keySet(),
  'Expected the set to contain one value called success'
);
```